# What is really happening when we change encoding in a string?

Tags: php, character-encoding, text-encoding

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Say I do:

```
$encoded = mb_convert_encoding ($original);
```

That looks like simple enough. WHat I am imagining is the following

`$original` has a pointer to the way the string is actually encoded. Something like `char *` kind of thing. And then there are things like what the character actually encoded.

It's probably somewhere along UTF-64 kind of thing where each glyph is indeed a character.

Now when we do

```
$encoded = mb_convert_encoding ($original);
```

several thing can happen:

- the original internal representation doesn't change however it is REINTERPRETED so that the code that show up differs
- the original string that it represent doesn't change however the ENCODING change.

Which one is right?

Comment: nameless downvote trolls. :(

Comment: Voting is anonymous, no one is required to explain their down votes.

Comment: I know. But why would anyone downvote this question? Any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string isn't a bag of bytes and a specification of the encoding : in most languages a string is a bag of bytes, and in best cases an implicit encoding defined by the language. It's your responsability as a coder to know what to do depending on the encoding (edit : as tdhammer pointed, most modern language explicitly forbids manipulating strings in other encoding than the implicitely defined one).

When you use an encoding function, you don't set a mention somewhere that the string uses a different encoding, you changes the bytes (the internal representation) so that it is correct regarding the intended encoding. But you must keep trace yourself of the used encoding.

For example, if you change the encoding of a string to UTF-16, strlen will give you an incorrect result (at least if you expect it to be the number of characters) because it will count the bytes. You must use [mb-strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and precise the encoding.

Comment: Actually, many languages (the entire .NET ecosystem, Python, Haskell, ...) treat strings as just that, strings, and convert them to bags-of-bytes when required.

Comment: I think that .Net internally uses UTF-16 just like Java. And you can't legally have in Haskell a string that is in another encoding than UTF-16, but you're right in that Haskell strings are arrays of Char (and not bytes).

Comment: IIRC, it's UTF-8, but that doesn't matter. What matters is that the internal string encoding is transparent, that is, they could change it to UTF-16 or UTF-32 at will, without breaking anything at the API level. A string is, conceptually, a different data type than a byte array, and going from one to the other requires an explicit conversion. In PHP, by contrast, both are just strings (just like in C), and you can assign them raw, breaking the encoding in horrible ways.

Comment: Also, UTF-16 *is* part of Unicode.

Comment: @tdammers what you say is right, of course, that's what I meant by an implicitly defined encoding for some languages, versus what OP seems to imply : an encoding different for each string and accompanying the string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PHP treats strings as bags-of-bytes, not making any distinction between bytestrings and 'proper' strings, and it doesn't track the encoding of these bytestrings.

An encoding is, basically, a mapping of byte sequences to proper string codepoints. So what `mb_convert_encoding` does is split the given string into appropriate byte sequences according to the input encoding, translate them into code points, and then back into byte sequences based on the target encoding.

Since many encodings do not define all the code points, and some encodings may treat certain byte sequences as invalid (e.g. ASCII does not allow anything above 127), you can specify what PHP should do when it encounters such a situation.

Note that `mb_convert_encoding` has two parameters that specify the input and output encodings (`to` and `from`); if you don't specify the `from_encoding`, the currently set internal encoding is used. You should always set the internal encoding to UTF-8, unless you have convincing reasons not to.

Comment: What do you mean by PhP not keeping track the encoding of these bytestrings? Does PhP use UTF-8?

Comment: Where can I learn more about it? I am imagining that PhP must have a class "String" which contain a char * and an enum encoding kind of thingy. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JimThio: PHP stores strings as byte sequences, and its string functions are completely ignorant of any encoding - they just operate on bytes. There is a multibyte-string API, but it requires you to tell it what the encoding is, and strings are still byte sequences.

Comment: PHP does not have a `String` class; the string type is wired into the language, and it stores an array of bytes and a length, but no encoding. You can globally set an internal encoding, and you can pass an encoding to some functions, but that's about it.